# jquery toggle class & mouseup button issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, mouseup

I am using 2 script's, as shown below.

The 1st script open's a div when a button is clicked with the class of "bookaviewing".

I need the div with the class "booking-form" to close when someone click's outside of the "booking-form" div - the 2nd script does this.

My issue is when you click the button more than once (as it's outside of the "booking-form" div), it won't close the "booking-form"... it just keeps opening.

I need to combine the 2 below scripts & need assistance.

**Script 1**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// set click/toggle event on bookaviewing button to show form
$('.bookaviewing').click(function () {
    $('.booking-form').slideToggle(400).toggleClass('opened');
    return false;
});
</script>
```

**Script 2**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// close booking-form when click outside of div
$(document).mouseup(function (e){
    var bookingform = $(".booking-form");
    if (!bookingform.is(e.target) && bookingform.has(e.target).length === 0){
        bookingform.hide();
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: If ur script1 only gives issue ,then only post script1 ,Not 2

Comment: I posted both of them as I think they need to be combined. Both work individually, but not together - as the button won't close the div.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your HTML too. Makes mocking up a demo so much faster.

Comment: It works Awesomely http://jsfiddle.net/ta0pdxkj/  Whats issue?

Comment: @jQuery Angry Bird: `slideToggle` should... wait for it... `toggle` the `slide` :) Your example does not close when you press the "clk" again.

Comment: take a look here - jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/philiplocke/Lztfrzta/

Comment: disable button for a while

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to exclude the booking form *and* the toggle button, to avoid the toggle open/closing at the same time:

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/4vnvpcjb/3/

```
// set click/toggle event on bookaviewing button to show form
$('.bookaviewing').click(function () {
    $('.booking-form').slideToggle(400).toggleClass('opened');
    return false;
});
$(document).on('mouseup', function (e){
    var bookingform = $(".booking-form");
    if (!bookingform.is(e.target) 
         && bookingform.has(e.target).length === 0 
         && !$(e.target).is('.bookaviewing'))
    {
        bookingform.slideUp();
    }
});
```

Note: *I changed the click outside, from `hide()` to `slideUp` as well, as `hide` was a bit jarring.*